# AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I'm using python 2.7.
In that code, listen_list is a list with UDP and TCP sockets, and the error must be happen when the TCP socket is closed because client disconnects from server. I don't know because in the other parts of the program the errors is OK but in this line I get that error.

```
import sys #for exit
import socket #for sockets
import select

listen_list = copy.copy(UDPlist) #list with listening udp sockets
listen_list.append(mySocket) #mySocket is a TCP socket for connect with client
try:
    rlist, wlist, elist = select.select(listen_list, [], [], 5)
except socket.error:
   print 'Failed. There is some socket that is invalid'
   listen_list = delete()
   continue
```

When I run the server, it works until it hits this error

```
File "server.py", line 67, in <module>
except socket.error:
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: Try putting a generic `except Exception as e:` for your except statement, and print out the value of e.  That will tell you the exception that is being generated, if any.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. If your issue is just that ``socket.error`` is undefined, a simple ``from socket import error`` should be enough. Otherwise, please provide *working* code to reproduce the issue – the current code has at least one ``SyntaxError`` and one undefined name.

Comment: Note that the error message suggest that ``socket`` actually refers to ``socket.socket``, which is an alias for ``socket._socketobject``.

Comment: If you don't except, what error exception is raised?

Answer (score 0):

The `_socketobject` is the type referred to by `socket.socket`. The error message shows that somewhere in the code, `socket` was bound to an instance of `socket.socket`, shadowing the module.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket = socket.socket()   # this happens somewhere in your code
>>> socket.error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Remove the assignment to `socket`, e.g. chose a different name, to make the module and its content accessible.

```
>>> import socket
>>> some_socket = socket.socket()   # this should be done instead
>>> socket.error
<class 'socket.error'>
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the docs, socket.error was deprecated since Python 3.3 and OSError is raised instead.

> starting from Python 3.3, errors related to socket or address
> semantics raise OSError or one of its subclasses (they used to raise
> socket.error).

Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html for more details.

Comment: The OP stated he is using Python 2.7.  Maybe he is mistaken?

Comment: But I'm using python 2.7. It's a project for college and the teachers always use socket.error, but I always use this without problem so I don't know what happens in this part. Thanks you anyway!

Comment: Are you sure you are running it on python 2.7? Can you double-check `sys.executable`